# How to htaccess a file to be displayed from other domain?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a domain a.com with a file called style.css. And i have cookieless domain b.com. Both are on the same server. Now what i would like to acomplish is to write a htaccess rule that states:

if user wants to take b.com/style.css display him the file from the a.com/style.css folder.

I want to acomplish it with htaccess because i don't want to involve PHP to do this (performance issue) and i would like it to work transparent for the browser. What i mean the browser asks for file from b domain and gets it from b domain.

How to acomplish it with htaccess and does it impact performance?

Comment: Are both domains sharing same `DOCUMENT_ROOT`?

Comment: Any reason you can't just use a symbolic link in the file system?

Comment: I have only FTP access, how to make a symbolic link? THey have other DOCUMENT_ROOT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?b\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ http://a.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]
```

This **does change** change the URL to `a.com/style.css`.

If you don't want external redirection then only way out is to `mod_proxy` which may not be enabled already on your host. **If you enable `mod_proxy` on `b.com` then you can try:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?b\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ http://a.com%{REQUEST_URI} [P,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thx. How to tell if mod_proxy is enabled? And what in this rule makes it use of modproxy?

Comment: It is the P flag in 2nd rule that makes use of it. I would suggest using first rule since it doesn't require any special config.

Comment: To know whether mod_proxy is enabled you will need to contact site admin.